# SOAP API- This Account lacks sufficient permissions

Tags: docusignapi

```
I am getting below error while accessing DocuSign SOAP service using SOAP UI tool. I also tried using integration key in username [Integration Key]userguid format I got same exception.
```

Can you please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Trying retrieve Authoritative copy using SOAP UI tool. Got above error error.

Comment: What's the actual SOAP API call you are trying to make here?  There are several related to Authoritative Copy, please specify.

Comment: <wsse:UsernameToken>
<wsse:Username>[Integrator Key]</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password>xxxxx</wsse:Password>
<wsse:Nonce>RumCR4p6U4a7hiX9lUlGWA==</wsse:Nonce> 
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>  
   <soapenv:Body> 
      <ns:ExportAuthoritativeCopy>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ns:EnvelopeId>B6A66D24-FB1D-4EB1-BE25-08A44F5C53B1</ns:EnvelopeId>
      </ns:ExportAuthoritativeCopy>
   </soapenv:Body>

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ergin. I am trying to use ExportAuthoritativeCopy soap Api call.

Comment: What is your account ID?  I think there might be an account option I need to enable on your account...

Comment: API UserName: 5bc2d1eb-b3a8-4215-82cd-d5e4dc083713
API AccountId: 854c6049-b8b6-4fbe-9707-c5c7a205ad65 Account ID:301222

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've found out which option it is, and have enabled this option on your account.  You should be able to export authoritative copies from this account now.  For reference sake, the option I enabled was a member setting called

```
Can Export Authoritative Copies?
```

Please note, though, that since this is a setting that we have to enable on DocuSign's side, that means that it might be an enterprise or workgroup level feature.  On your demo account we enable whatever you like so you can test things out, however when you are ready to move to production and purchase a corresponding production account that uses the API, you'll need to make sure you purchase an account that allows this feature.  You can find out more from your Account Manager.

Comment: Thanks Ergin, Still I am getting the same error. I think the option you enabled will make every document as Authoritative copy. But, I am looking for retrieving(Transfer to Cleint specific Vault from DocuSign vautlt) Authoritative copy after envelop is completed. In my account, In Permissions info page it's showing as Administrators,  Everyone in Groups.Can you please help me to resolve this exception?

Comment: Thanks Ergin for your solution.